# join e merge diagrama de atividade

Tags: uml, diagrama

Qual a diferença de Join e Merge no Diagrama de Atividade?

Gostaria de um exemplo simples de cada um deles para entender melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um Merge é representado graficamente por um losango com duas ou mais entradas e apenas uma saída , por exemplo: 
Ao pagar o estacionamento o fluxo seria :
[image: Fluxograma exemplificando o merge]
Note que independente da escolha de pagamento o fluxo converge para uma única saída.

Um Join,  é representado por uma barra sólida que tenha duas ou mais entradas e uma saída, entenda ele como uma sincronização de atividades paralelas, ao fazer uma compra no e-commerce o fluxo seria :
[image: Fluxograma exemplificando o join]
Note que as duas atividades não dependem uma da outra, porém só após ambas tendo sidas completadas que você pode partir para a próxima.

Você pode usar esse material pra tirar mais dúvidas sobre esses elementos : 
http://www.theclub.com.br/restrito/revistas/201310/umld1310.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Sobre o **Merge** (Consulte a [referência 1](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#merge-node))

> O Merge é um nó de controle que reúne vários **fluxos alternativos** de entrada para aceitar o fluxo de saída único. Não há junção de tokens. O merge **não deve ser usado para sincronizar fluxos simultâneos** - Um merge reúne vários fluxos sem sincronização.

Sobre o **Join**  (Consulte a [referência 2](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#join-node))

> O Join é um nó de controle que possui várias arestas de entrada e uma aresta de saída e é **usado para sincronizar fluxos simultâneos de entrada**. Os Joins são introduzidos para suportar o **paralelismo nas atividades** .

Por exemplo, no diagrama abaixo:

- Toda vez que eu me referir a mesclagem ou mesclados, subentende-se que estou falando de um merge.

Uma decisão é usada após um Fork, os dois fluxos que saem da decisão **precisam ser mesclados(Merge) em um, para ai sim ir para um Join**.

**Por quê?** Caso contrário, o Join aguardará pelos dois fluxos.

Então , *Activity2* e *Activity3* são nossos **fluxos alternativos** e apenas **um deles** chegará. E eles **não** estão sincronizando a entrada.

No entanto , o *Concurrent_Activity* e o resultado da decisão entre *Activity1* e *Activity2*(que é mesclado(merge) em uma saída) estão sincronizando os fluxos simultâneos de entrada. O Join espera que ambos funcionem e continuem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]